# Should I write the definition again for using rewrite in Agda?

Tags: agda, plfa

##### Exercise `*-assoc` (recommended) {#times-assoc}

Show multiplication is associative, that is,

```
(m * n) * p ≡ m * (n * p)
```

for all naturals `m`, `n`, and `p`.

```
*-assoc : ∀ (m n p : ℕ) → (m * n) * p ≡ m * (n * p)
*-assoc zero n p = refl

*-assoc (suc m) n p = 
  begin
    ((suc m) * n) * p 
  ≡⟨ cong (_* p) (suc-*-comm m n) ⟩
    (n + (m * n)) * p
  ≡⟨ (*-distrib-+ n (m * n) p) ⟩
    n * p + (m * n) * p
  ≡⟨ cong ((n * p) +_) (*-assoc m n p) ⟩
    n * p + m * (n * p)
  ≡⟨⟩
    (suc m) * (n * p)
  ∎
  where 
  suc-*-comm : ∀ (m n : ℕ) → (suc m) * n ≡ n + m * n
  suc-*-comm m n = refl
```

I need to rewrite the definition of multiplication here. It is annoying.

I have tried to add the definition of multiplication in the where. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand what you are asking, nor why this might be "annoying" (not really a technical matter, unless you think the definition of multiplication to be somehow incorrect. or for there to be a 'better' definition?), but it may help you to know that, for your definition of `suc-*-comm m n = refl` in the `where` block, the first step in the main proof,

```
    ((suc m) * n) * p 
  ≡⟨ cong (_* p) (suc-*-comm m n) ⟩
    (n + (m * n)) * p
```

reduces to

```
    ((suc m) * n) * p 
  ≡⟨ cong (_* p) refl ⟩
    (n + (m * n)) * p
```

and hence to

```
    ((suc m) * n) * p 
  ≡⟨ refl ⟩
    (n + (m * n)) * p
```

and hence, analogously to the final step, finally to

```
    ((suc m) * n) * p 
  ≡⟨⟩
    (n + (m * n)) * p
```

As a consequence of which, you will no longer need the `where` block...

```
*-assoc (suc m) n p = 
  begin-equality
    ((suc m) * n) * p 
  ≡⟨⟩
    (n + (m * n)) * p
  ≡⟨ ... ⟩
    n * p + (m * n) * p
  ≡⟨ cong ((n * p) +_) (*-assoc m n p) ⟩
    n * p + m * (n * p)
  ≡⟨⟩
    (suc m) * (n * p)
  ∎
```

(the `...` here is because using stdlib-v2.0, a different proof of distributivity is required in that step)

Comment: Thank you. But it fails on the second reduction. When I tried `≡⟨ cong (_* p) refl ⟩` there is an error message `Failed to solve the following constraints:
  _x_429 * p = (n + m * n) * p : ℕ (blocked on _x_429)`

Comment: Did you try the final reduced version, without appeal to`refl` at all? You're correct, in as much as Agda can't infer the arguments (in particular, the first one) to an instance of multiplication, so `≡⟨ cong (_* p) refl ⟩ ` indeed needs `refl` to know its *implicit* argument. But the final version, should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! I finally worked out. It seems like... I typed a space between `⟨⟩`. `((suc m) * n) * p ≡⟨⟩ (n + (m * n)) * p` succeeded but `((suc m) * n) * p ≡⟨ ⟩ (n + (m * n)) * p` failed...

Comment: Yes! Watch out for whitespace!